# how to include code snippet from one php file to another one?

Tags: php

i have just learned about `include()` function in php, which enables to include whole document into another document. i was wondering how to do the same, if i would like to include not a whole document, but only a snippet of code, from one document into another one.

Comment: why dont you put that snippet in an extra file?

Comment: i just wonder if there is a way to include snippets, like including whole documents.

Comment: Write all those snippet as a function in a file and call those functions instead of "include" all the time. And dont forgot to include the file at the top of your code. Hope this help

function Snip1{}
function Snip2{}
function Snip3()

include_once("SnipCollection.php")

Comment: thanks, looks like there is no way to include() snippets directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with 2 approach:

- You can go with @blckbird idea and put your code in a new file and just include it.
- You can create a file containing a method foo(), with your snip code. include the file and just call that foo().

Exmple:

// helper.php - contain your snip/reusable code

```
<?php 

function startPage($title){
    print '
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>'.$title.'</title>
        </head>
        <body>';
}

function endPage(){
    print '
        </body>
    </html>';'
}

?>
```

Now your main file include helper.php and call the method you want.
// main.php

```
<?php 

include("helper.php");

startPage("My Title");

// do your stuff/coding here

endPage();
?>
```

hope it helps a bit.